# windows-8 : Certain process running under username "DWM-1" and "ANONYMOUS LOGON"

Tags: windows, windows-8, user-accounts, login, process

I have window-8 installed on checking the taskmanager I found the following details :

1. dwm(Desktop Window Manager) was running under username "DWM-1".
2. "SandboxieDcomLaunch.exe", "SandboxieRpcSs.exe" and application running inside [sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)  are  running under username  "ANONYMOUS LOGON".

[image: taskmanager screenshot].

---

---

On checking the security logs in the eventviewer I found the following information :

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        **NULL SID**
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Type:         3

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        ANONYMOUS LOGON
    Account Name:       ANONYMOUS LOGON
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x1F481
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   NTLM V1
    Key Length:     0
```

---

---

On running following command in the Powershell, I found "ANONYMOUS LOGON" listed in the win32_system_account list.

> get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | sort
>   caption | format-table caption, __CLASS, FullName

```
caption                                 __CLASS                                 FullName                               
-------                                 -------                                 --------                               
PCX\Access Control Assistance Opera... Win32_Group                                                                    
pcx\Administrator                      Win32_UserAccount                                                              
PCX\Administrators                     Win32_Group                                                                    
**PCX\ANONYMOUS LOGON**                    Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Authenticated Users                Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Backup Operators                   Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\BATCH                              Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\BUILTIN                            Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\CREATOR GROUP                      Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\CREATOR GROUP SERVER               Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\CREATOR OWNER                      Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\CREATOR OWNER SERVER               Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Cryptographic Operators            Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\DIALUP                             Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Distributed COM Users              Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\ENTERPRISE DOMAIN CONTROLLERS      Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Event Log Readers                  Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\Everyone                           Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
pcx\Guest                              Win32_UserAccount                                                              
PCX\Guests                             Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\Hyper-V Administrators             Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\IIS_IUSRS                          Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\INTERACTIVE                        Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\IUSR                               Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\LOCAL                              Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\LOCAL SERVICE                      Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\NETWORK                            Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Network Configuration Operators    Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\NETWORK SERVICE                    Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\OWNER RIGHTS                       Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Performance Log Users              Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\Performance Monitor Users          Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\Power Users                        Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\PROXY                              Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Remote Desktop Users               Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\REMOTE INTERACTIVE LOGON           Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Remote Management Users            Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\Replicator                         Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\RESTRICTED                         Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\SELF                               Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\SERVICE                            Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\SYSTEM                             Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
pcx/CYBORG                         Win32_UserAccount                                                              
PCX\TERMINAL SERVER USER               Win32_SystemAccount                                                            
PCX\Users                              Win32_Group                                                                    
PCX\WinRMRemoteWMIUsers__              Win32_Group
```

---

---

---

Can somebody explain me what going around ? what "DWM-1" and "ANONYMOUS LOGON" are , I have never seen process running under such usernames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `DWM-#` user is new in Windows 8; it's a system user that is used only for the `Desktop Window Manager` process.

The other user is `NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON` which is also a system user.

#### Related

- Microsoft TechNet Forums: [*Why Desktop Windows Manager states DWM-2,DWM3,DWM-1 in task manager*](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/02331520-d044-471b-84f4-5a0a898c3589/why-desktop-windows-manager-states-dwm2dwm3dwm1-in-task-manager?forum=w8itprosecurity)

Comment: I goggled a lot but didn't found any good explanation . Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: any source for that claim?